# Having trouble loading image to screen

Tags: java, image, loading, bufferedimage

I am making a game and I am stuck trying to get the image to screen. I states that-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

I am sure that my image path is the right path, but it keeps stating that it's not.

```
background = new Background("C:/hello/flappybird.png");
```

The "debug" section of my workspace states that there is a problem with

```
background.render(g);
```

specifically, with

```
g.drawImage(img,(int)x,(int)y,null);
```

and I have no idea why it is doing this. I am 100% sure my build path is right!

EDIT: just incase you want to know the constructor of the background class:

```
public Background(String s) {

      try {
        img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(s));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

Comment: Can we see the constructor of the Background class?

Comment: Compiler realized you're trying to make a flappy bird clone and decided not to be part of it.

Comment: hahahaha that's pretty funny XD don't worry it's just my own project XD XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution!

it seems that in gamePanel, after I declared my BufferedImage, I forgot to add-

`Graphics g = image.getGraphics();`

sorry guys, I feel so stupid XD

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates the image file wasn't found. To be sure that this is really the case, I urge you to execute `ImageIO.read()` directly and check the result:

```
BufferedImage icon = ImageIO.read("C:/hello/flappybird.png");
```

Also, it's not a good practice to use resources outside the classpath. I strongly suggest you to change your class `Background` to use classpath resources. Somewhere inside your `Background` class, you could add:

```
public class Background {

    public Background(String filename) {
        // Some code here
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/images/" + filename));
        // More code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I took your latter advice, but it still has the error. I am absolutely sure that the flappybird.png is in that directory. I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Does the error you are talking about happen when you execute `ImageIO.read()` alone?